# DNS not resolving using IP rule for dialup modem

Tags: linux, dns, routing

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

I have a HSDPA USB Modem, with which I can successfully dial in. It works fine as well when I set the default gateway (remote IP address) in the main routing table. But I would like to use this modem in parallel to my WLAN, which will be the main interface, and therefore occupy the default gateway in the main table.

I want to send packets through the modem only from sockets on the local IP address assigned by  dialing. Thus I introduced a new rule in the IP rule table `from x.x.x.x lookup table 1`, where I used the local IP address. Then in the table I simply added the `default via x.x.x.x dev ppp0` where I used the remote IP address provided by the dialing process.

Now, if I turn of my WLAN and remove the default rule in the main table, I cannot resolve any host. I can however use `traceroute` to trace a path to the primary DNS server (Address also supplied by the dialing). If I add the default rule back to the main table, everything works fine again.

So, I suspected that the IP from rule would do its job, but somehow somewhere packets are apparently dropping. Can anyone suggest or hint to a solution to my problem?

**EDIT:**

By adding the primary (and secondary if you like) nameserver to the ip rule list of to address, `from all to x.x.x.x lookup table 1`, I can actually retrieve host information, i.e. I can e.g. run `host google.com` successfully. But even by forcing ping to use the **ppp0** interface, `ping google.com -I ppp0`, I cannot reach it, **Network is unreachable**.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS server is determined by /etc/resolv.conf (Ubuntu has annoying "helpers" the write to this file) To have the IP 10.11.12.13 be the nameserver used for name lookups, have /etc/resolv.conf look like this:

nameserver 10.11.12.13

A DNS setup where one nameserver resolves some IPs and another nameserver resolves other IPs is more complicated, but I have one documented here:

http://maradns.samiam.org/deadwood/doc/Deadwood-HOWTO

Comment: I had noticed that file, yes. For the wlan there is a nameserver as well as a dns-search entry. For the ppp0 interface there are two nameserver entries (primary and secondary addresses). When the wlan goes down, the latter two remain there. So I think that works properly.

Comment: When you have multiple nameserver entries in /etc/resolv.conf, it just uses one of the nameservers at random.

Comment: @samiam no, not at random. The documentation says: "If there are multiple servers, the  resolver library  queries  them  in the order listed.". Except if you have `options rotate`, in which case it will do a round-robing walk from the list (so still not random)